# Keep local copy of Nuget Package in VS Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, nuget, omnisharp, nuget-package-manager-console

In Visual Studio Code, i would like to keep a local copy of a referenced Nuget package in the project folder for the case the package will not be available online for some reason in the future.

`nuget restore` shall still be able to download it from the internet if the local copy is not yet there.

I think thats exactly the behaviour with Visual Studio, but i can't get this running with Visual Studio Code

Comment: Have a look into ["local nuget feed"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/hosting-packages/local-feeds).

Answer (score 0):

I think i found a solution myself.

Adding a file called `nuget.config` with the following content to the project folder does exactly what I wanted. The packages are now put into the local `packages` folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<config>
    <add key="globalPackagesFolder" value="packages" />
    <add key="repositoryPath" value="packages" />
</config>
</configuration>
```